# perform operation on all rows and add results back to main data frame

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

I have a rather large dataset (15.000 rows) and I need to make calculations on each row due to the data structure. There is one column in my data set, that needs to be split further. Below is an example:

```
date <- c("2015-07-10", "2013-05-06", "2017-08-10")
Number <- c(345, 231, 10)
Route <- c("GCLP:10011:-8848:56:-4:270:260:12;LPC:1211:-828:56:-2:22:220:22;GCCC:13451:-85458:556:-45:45:76:67", "DPAP:10011:-8848:56:-4:270:260:12;LTTC:1211:-828:56:-2:22:220:22;ATCH:13451:-85458:556:-45:45:76:67", "AMN:10011:-8848:56:-4:270:260:12;RET:1211:-828:56:-2:22:220:22;LLOP:13451:-85458:556:-45:45:76:67")

Dep <- c("FGC","HAM","ICAO")
Plan <- data.frame(date, Number, Route, Dep)
```

For me the important information is in the column "Route". I need to generate aggreagted features from this column. The information in each cell of the column needs to be split by the ";"

What I tried so far:

1. select one row
2. create a new data frame just with this one row.
3. use mutate and unnest on the column "Route" to split it at the ";" points and create a new row for each

   test <- Plan[1,]
   test <- test %>% mutate(Route=strsplit(as.character(Route), ";")) %>% unnest(Route)
4. use cSplit to split the information in the column "Route" by the ":"

   ```
    test = cSplit(test, "Route", ":")
   ```
5. I then perform my calculations on this subset of the data.
6. I create variables x,y,z to save my calculations

   ```
     x1 <- mean(test$Route_2)
     y1 <- max(test$Route_5)
     z1 <- min(test$Route_8)
   ```

**The TWO QUESTIONS:**

How can I automate this operation for all rows in my original dataset?
How to I merge the data in the saved variables(x,y,z) back to my original data frame?

**DESIRED OUTPUT**
(these are not the actual values from the data for x2 and x3, just an example)

```
x1 <- 12
y1 <- 86363
z1 <- 7383
x2 <- 45
y2 <- 6754
z2 <- 3553
x3 <- 5648
y3 <- 64
z3 <- 6363

Plan$x <- c(x1,x2,x3)
Plan$y <- c(y1, y2, y3)
Plan$z <- c(z1,z2,z3)

head(Plan)
```

**FULL SAMPLE CODE ALL AT ONCE**

```
library(splitstackshape)
library(plyr)
library(tidyr)

date <- c("2015-07-10", "2013-05-06", "2017-08-10")
Number <- c(345, 231, 10)
Route <- c("GCLP:10011:-8848:56:-4:270:260:12;LPC:1211:-828:56:-2:22:220:22;GCCC:13451:-85458:556:-45:45:76:67", "DPAP:10011:-8848:56:-4:270:260:12;LTTC:1211:-828:56:-2:22:220:22;ATCH:13451:-85458:556:-45:45:76:67", "AMN:10011:-8848:56:-4:270:260:12;RET:1211:-828:56:-2:22:220:22;LLOP:13451:-85458:556:-45:45:76:67")

Dep <- c("FGC","HAM","ICAO")

Plan <- data.frame(date, Number, Route, Dep)

test <- Plan[1,]
test <- test %>% mutate(Route=strsplit(as.character(Route), ";")) %>% unnest(Route)
test = cSplit(test, "Route", ":")

x1 <- mean(test$Route_2)
y1 <- max(test$Route_5)
z1 <- min(test$Route_8)

x2 <- 45
y2 <- 6754
z2 <- 3553
x3 <- 5648
y3 <- 64
z3 <- 6363

Plan$x <- c(x1,x2,x3)
Plan$y <- c(y1, y2, y3)
Plan$z <- c(z1,z2,z3)

head(Plan)
```

Comment: Please include your desired output for the example data.frame you provided. I suspect that you want `strsplit`, but am not entirely sure of the final data.frame.

Comment: The `separate` function in the `tidyr` package may be helpful here

Comment: @G.Grothendieck I hope that the sample code helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a second temporary Route column called `Route_tmp` and from it generate a separate row for each component of it splitting by semicolon and then separate the resulting `Route_tmp` variable by colon into separate columns. Now grouping by the original variables we take the mean of the required columns.  (Note that if we did not need `Route` in the output then we could have omitted the `mutate` at top and used `Route` in place of `Route_tmp`.)

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

out <- Plan %>% 
     mutate(Route_tmp = Route) %>%
     separate_rows(Route_tmp, sep = ";") %>% 
     separate(Route_tmp, as.character(1:8), convert = TRUE) %>% 
     group_by(date, Number, Route, Dep) %>% 
     summarize(x = mean(`2`), y = mean(`5`), z = mean(`8`)) %>%
     ungroup
```

giving the following (we do not show the Route column to make it easier to read):

```
> out[-3]
# A tibble: 3 × 6
        date Number    Dep        x     y        z
      <fctr>  <dbl> <fctr>    <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>
1 2013-05-06    231    HAM 8224.333    17 33.66667
2 2015-07-10    345    FGC 8224.333    17 33.66667
3 2017-08-10     10   ICAO 8224.333    17 33.66667
```

**Note:** Since Plan is overwritten in the question it was not clear to me precisely which version of Plan was the input but I have assumed this:

```
Plan <- data.frame(date = c("2015-07-10", "2013-05-06", "2017-08-10"),
          Number = c(345, 231, 10),
          Route = c("GCLP:10011:-8848:56:-4:270:260:12;LPC:1211:-828:56:-2:22:220:22;GCCC:13451:-85458:556:-45:45:76:67", "DPAP:10011:-8848:56:-4:270:260:12;LTTC:1211:-828:56:-2:22:220:22;ATCH:13451:-85458:556:-45:45:76:67", "AMN:10011:-8848:56:-4:270:260:12;RET:1211:-828:56:-2:22:220:22;LLOP:13451:-85458:556:-45:45:76:67"),
          Dep = c("FGC","HAM","ICAO"))
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I'd do it using `tidyverse` packages:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)
library(purrr)
# This function takes a single item from Plan$Route, splits it into its
# relevant columns and then finds the mean of columns 2, 5 and 8.
route_extract <- function(route) {
  cols <- str_split(route, fixed(":"), simplify = TRUE)[, c(2, 5, 8), drop = FALSE]
  # Converts the matrix to numeric without losing dimensions
  storage.mode(cols) <- "numeric"
  # Calculate the column means and then return the result as a `tibble`
  cm <- colMeans(cols)
  tibble(x = cm[1], y = cm[2], z = cm[3])
}
route_calc <- function(routes) {
  str_split(routes, fixed(";")) %>%
    map_df(route_extract)

}

Plan <- bind_cols(Plan, route_calc(Plan$Route))
```